# JavaFX permanently maximized window

Tags: java, javafx, window, windows-10, maximize-window

As the title suggests, I want to make window in JavaFX and make it permanently maximized (i.e. fullscreen).

This is sample code that produces error... well, unexpected behavior.

```
public class Resize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Please note `setMaximized` and `setResizable`. Everything works until... I press <kbd>***⊞***</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> (`WinKey`+`DownArrow`), at which point my window gets resized, and I can't get it maximized again. I'm running the code from **NetBeans** on **Windows 10**.

Here's a screenshot. [image: screenshot].

Comment: try adding setFullScreen(true) on the primaryStage

Comment: That fixed it... but now I can press `ESC` and it gets resized again. Is there a way to make my application either fullscreen or minimized, but never windowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the application to be either full screen or minimized, but never windowed, as per your comment, by first doing

primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

and then disabling the ability to exit full screen by doing

primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);